# Path issue with d3 zoomable sunburst

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to d3. Using the basic "flare.json" from mbostock, I'm trying to combine 2 features of the zoomable sunbust:

ability to toggle between size/count
addition of text labels [see etmajers example](http://bl.ocks.org/metmajer/5480307)

Adding labels requires access to svg 'g' element, but toggling to count seems to require a path partitioned from the root without access to 'g'.

path for count/size toggle:

```
 var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
.data(partition.nodes)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
.on("click", click)
.each(stash);
```

path for text labels is set in 2 parts:

```
var g = svg.selectAll("g")
.data(partition.nodes(root))
.enter().append("g");

var path = g.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
.on("click", click);
```

The issue is when toggling between count and size the path is not reset

```
path
.data(partition.value(value).nodes)
.transition()
.attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
```

any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just came to say thanks for posting a good first question. It's nice to see some decent questions in the triage queue.

Comment: Can you give a fiddle that your problem is in?

Comment: I posted to jsfiddle but for some reason the sunburst is not rendering on jsfiddle.. I can run it locally but can't toggle between size/count as mentioned.
https://jsfiddle.net/mrl513/ko3ppggj/4/